# Bash check for http or https regex

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if a url starts with http|https and ends with jpg|png. I have searched, but the answers don't work for me.

I have this currently:

```
if [[ $url = ^https?://.*jpg ]]
then
wget -O webcam.jpg $url
fi
```

But its fails to `wget`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `=~` operator for regular-expression matching; `=` only does *pattern* matching. The equivalent pattern would be `http?(s)://*jpg*`. (Recent versions of `bash` always use extended patterns inside `[[ ... ]]`; older versions may require they be turned on explicitly with `shopt -s extglob`.)

(I added the trailing `*` to the pattern because patterns are anchored to both ends of the string by default, while regular expressions require `^` and `$` explicitly. Since you did not have `$` at the end of your regular expression, I made the pattern open at the end as well.)

Comment: Won't adding a trailing `*` match a URL like `http://jpg.com/not_an_image.html`? I think OP wants exact matching, not substring matching.